# When ever I try onclick function, I get reference error

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to use the on-click event in my javascript file. But, whenever, I use it, it says that the function is declared, but never used. Can you please help me resolve this issue? You can check the code below, as well as in the image.

```
let showtoDos = () => {
  let li = "";
  if(toDos) {
  toDos.forEach((todo, id) => {
    li += `<li class="task">
        <label for="${id}">
          <input class="clicked" type="checkbox" id="${id}" />
          <p>${todo.name}</p>
        </label>
        <div class="settings">
          <i id="ellipsis" class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
          <ul class="task-menu">
            <li><i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>Edit</li>
            <li onclick="deleteTask(${id})" class="delete" ><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>`;
  });
}
  taskBox.innerHTML = li;
}
showtoDos();

function deleteTask(deletedId) {
  console.log(deletedId);
}
```

[image: picture of the code in vscode]

Moreover, you can check in the below image that, whenever I click on the delete button on the browser, it gives a reference error.

[image: code in the browser]

Comment: VSCode can't analyze the code in your onClick because it's a string, not code. You can add a // @ts-ignore comment above it if you want to populate our innerHTML this way

Comment: `deleteTask` doesn't exist in global scope. It only exists in the scope of your module, since webpack is bundling your files. Don't use `onclick` at all, use an event listener instead, then you don't have this problem.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. Do you mean that when Webpack bundles our files? We can't use "onclick" at all? Or I can use it by applying the "// @ts-ignore comment". Once again thank you for your reply. And I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different problems there:

1. The IDE is doing validation of your code showing warnings and can't
   find any line calling that function. The only point you targeted
   that function is when you defined the onclick attribute of the li
   element but it happened inside a string literal and it doesn't count
   for the linter. You can ignore this.
2. The javascript code you have in that file won't run in the global
   scope so the function defined there won't be visible to the li item
   when its event will fire. You should try attaching an event handler
   via javascript so to be sure the handler will be attached until you
   still have control of that scope.

Just after you `showToDos()` you can try to run the following:

```
//for each delete list item
document.querySelectorAll('li.task ul.task_menu li.delete')
  .forEach( (o, i) => {
    //bind an handler (deleteTask) for its click event (deleteTask should be in this scope now)
    o.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);
  });
```

**DISCLAIMER:**

Unfortunately that selector I used with `querySelectorAll` will get ALL those items even those that already got the handler attached (if any already existed with the same selector criteria). Before doing `addEventListener`, one strategy could be to check if there's already an handler for that event on that object.

A better solution would be to use that html code you crafted with a template string, create an html elements tree from there and call `querySelectorAll`(+attachEventHandler) from such object before appending it to taskbox. It wouldn't require you to make any check before attaching the event handler because you'll be targeting only the newly created ones.

Or you could as someone suggested to make that function available in the global scope but it wouldn't scale really well due to name collisions (this is one of the unsafe ways to do it):

```
var deleteTask = (/*args*/) => {/*code here*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your function in the global scope (window object in browser) if you want to access it like that, try:

```
  window.deleteTask = function (deletedId) {
  console.log(deletedId);
}
```